# Is it possible to validate XML against multiple schemas in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, multiple-schema

I'm wondering if it is possible to validate xml against multiple schemas in PHP or I have to merge my schemas somehow.

Thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem via simple PHP script:

```
$mainSchemaFile = dirname(__FILE__) . "/main-schema.xml";
$additionalSchemaFile = 'second-schema.xml';


$additionalSchema = simplexml_load_file($additionalSchemaFile);
$additionalSchema->registerXPathNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
$nodes = $additionalSchema->xpath('/xs:schema/*');    

$xml = '';  
foreach ($nodes as $child) {
  $xml .= $child->asXML() . "\n";
}

$result = str_replace("</xs:schema>", $xml . "</xs:schema>", file_get_contents($mainSchemaFile));

var_dump($result); // merged schema in form XML (string)
```

But it is possible only thanks to the fact that the schemas are the same - i.e.

```
<xs:schema xmlns="NAMESPACE"
           targetNamespace="NAMESPACE"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

is in both files.

Answer (score 4):

The main schema file must contain an include tag for each child schema file. For example:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="2nd_schema_file.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syfmony2 developers solved that problem. It's not freakin' clean but will do:

```
function validateSchema(\DOMDocument $dom)
{
    $tmpfiles = array();
    $imports = '';
    foreach ($this->schemaLocations as $namespace => $location) {
        $parts = explode('/', $location);
        if (preg_match('#^phar://#i', $location)) {
            $tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'sf2');
            if ($tmpfile) {
                file_put_contents($tmpfile, file_get_contents($location));
                $tmpfiles[] = $tmpfile;
                $parts = explode('/', str_replace('\\', '/', $tmpfile));
            }
        }
        $drive = '\\' === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ? array_shift($parts).'/' : '';
        $location = 'file:///'.$drive.implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', $parts));

        $imports .= sprintf('    <xsd:import namespace="%s" schemaLocation="%s" />' . PHP_EOL, $namespace, $location);
    }

    $source = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://symfony.com/schema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
$imports
</xsd:schema>
EOF
    ;

    $current = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $valid = $dom->schemaValidateSource($source);
    foreach ($tmpfiles as $tmpfile) {
        @unlink($tmpfile);
    }
    if (!$valid) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(implode("\n", $this->getXmlErrors()));
    }
    libxml_use_internal_errors($current);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the [**`DOMDocument::schemaValidate`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php) method receives the path to the schema file as a parameter, I'd say that you just have to call that method several times : once for each one of your schemas.

See also [**`DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidatesource.php) if you have your schemas in PHP strings ; the idea *(and the answer)* will be the same, though : just call the method several times.

Comment: It was also my guess but it doesn't work unfortunately. I guess I will have to merge my schemas.